# How do I stop program from adding individual letters of a 1 element tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I created a program that is supposed to take a tuple input, change it into a list, join the elements of that list into a single string, and then replace any occurrence of the word dark with light. If the tuple has only one element it adds each letter instead of just taking the element. My code is below with the intended outcome.

```
def dark_light(tup):
    new_list=list(tup)
    single_string=', '.join(new_list)
    print(single_string.replace("dark", "light"))


dark_light(("light", "dark", "light", "stop"))#light, light, light, stop
dark_light(("darkness bidarkee", "ok"))# lightness lightee, ok
dark_light(("darkroom bidarke"))#lightroom bilighte
dark_light(("enough", "jokes")) #enough, jokes
```

Comment: `("darkroom bidarke")` is not a one element tuple; `("darkroom bidarke",)` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you think is a one element tuple is actually a string.

```
>>> type(("darkroom bidarke"))
<type 'str'>
```

To initialize a one element tuple, you must have a trailing comma in your parentheses, like so:

```
>>> type(("darkroom bidarke",))
<type 'tuple'>
```

I think you'll be pleasantly surprised once you make this change. Here is the documentation on tuple syntax: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax